# What's the best site to get thorough help with android app development?

Tags: android, forum

I can't decide where I should take my android coding problems online. There's stackoverflow, but only specific questions seem appropriate whereas I'm really **looking for somewhere to get mentoring and where there are patient people happy to take the time to actually look through your code and help you identify problems.**

Many forums that seemed like likely subjects look pretty inactive to me or seem to have a ratio of one expert to hundreds of newbies.

So what would you recommend? I'm open to non-android specific sites too (of which their are many I know) if you think they would have what i'm looking for. And any other invlauable resource sites too.

Hope this kind of question is appropriate for stackoverflow, If not, apologies!

Comment: Whats wrong with asking advice on here? If you keep your questions specific and small it should be OK.

Comment: That's the thing, I can google/ask SO for the answer to a specific question but on occasions like today, when i've been working for many days trying to figure out why my code still isn't working, i'm really looking for somewhere to take it where people aren't bothered by huge code-dumps and might even take the time to go through it all with you to work out where you've gone wrong. That's the sort of site/forum I wanted to see if anyone had recommendations for. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://stackoverflow.com

(e.g. this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869338/where-to-start-to-learn-android/2869373#2869373)

Comment: None of those in the the answer were the sort of place I was looking for (an active, code trawling android community which I appreciate may not exist) but it's a great compendium of resources so thanks for posting it!

Comment: Yes but that's why I mentioned stackoverflow, because here all your questions are answered.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Holly!

This is a perfectly fine place to ask questions when you are teaching yourself how to develop software (be it Android or whatever). Here are lots of highly skillful people that enjoy helping people with this. There are however a few expectations when asking questions on Stack Overflow:

- First of all, you should read [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to understand few basics on how the site works.
- Secondly, the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page gives you many good hints on how to formulate a good question, some of the important being:

  - Do your homework: you should search for existing questions that answer what you're looking for - and also don't forget to do a web search as well
  - Be specific: make sure that people understand exactly what you're asking about, and preferably ask about one thing only in each question - this makes it much easier to answer
- And last: don't expect people to do the work for you. We are more than glad to help you out, but if it shows that you ask about something you haven't even tried to figure out yourself, people will not feel encouraged to help you.

[John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (famous Stack Overflow user, you'll learn that name soon enough) also has a nice blog post on [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). This is very much recommended to read.

If you only have a short question, or if your question is long and complex with lots of code attached to it, it doesn't matter: Stack Overflow is a great place to gain knowledge (and share knowledge!). So just keep the above points in mind, and I'll think you'll find this to be a nice place :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need tutorials on basic android stuff you can refer

http://www.bogotobogo.com/android.html

Comment: Really thorough informative site I hadn't found before, thank you very much for posting it!